# modbus TCP in PHP array byte to float

Tags: php, arrays, modbus

I have Problem with conversion 4 bytes to float value. I would like to read voltage.

[screen1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLfA1.png)

[screen2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQgTP.png)

As you can see in first 4 values I have:

> 67, 93, 135, 197

I think, that values 67 and 93 it's integer.

```
$recData = $modbus->readMultipleRegisters(1, 1, 6);
$Spannung1 = ($recData[3]<<24) + ($recData[2]<<16) +($recData[1]<<8) + $recData[0];
```

I don't know but value - $Spannung1 amount always other value for example one time -98098450 or 2092129347.

In reality voltage has 221V or 222V

please help

Comment: modbus doesn't have the concept of "voltage". It has integer registers which the `readMultipleRegisters` (really `Read Holding Registers`) request can be used to access. The way in which a device interface chooses to represent an analog value like voltage is not specified in modbus. So without knowing the device and software providing the values, there's no way anyone can help you.

Comment: I should also add that that modbus request actually returns a list of *16-bit* (2-byte) values in network (big-endian) order. For whatever reason, `phpmodbus` appears to return an array containing all the individual bytes (i.e. it does not reconstruct the original 16-bit values). When you put them back together with shift-and-add in your code, you're in effect treating the first four bytes as a single 32-bit value stored in little-endian order.  It's difficult to imagine any scenario where that would be correct.